# Android SwipeRefreshLayout disable refreshing by pulling

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-progressbar, swiperefreshlayout

I want to display a google map inside a SwipeRefreshLayout so that I get the fancy progress circle when refreshing markers. I noticed you can no longer move the map upward because it triggers the SwipeRefreshLayout. I already tried using `setDistanceToTriggerSync()`and it no longer refreshes when pulling, but I still cannot move he map upwards. The code I'm using:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/map_refresh">

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you don't wanna swipe to refresh, why do you need a `SwipeRefreshLayout`. If you just need to refresh the map, you can try to use `SyncAdapter` or `JobSchedule API`.

Comment: I just want the fancy loading circle

Answer (score 2):

To disable the gesture and progress animation,
call `setEnabled(false)` on the SwipeRefreshLayout view.

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by determining a limited area of ​​action. I used `getScrollY()`.

```
public boolean canSwipeRefresh(@NonNull SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout, @Nullable View view) { return webView.getScrollY() > 100; }
```

Therefore, `SwipeRefreshLayout` is only used when the activity content is on top of 0 to 100 dp

Answer (score 0):

If you need `loading circle` for `SwipeRefreshLayout`, make you map inside the `SwipeRefreshLayout` tag and use the `FrameLayout` for the parent view group.

You can try the code as follows:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: How do you solve it? Did I help you or ring the bell for you?

Comment: I just copied the SwipeRefreshLayout class into my project and modified it to fit my needs

Comment: I'm having the same problem, could you please post the answer?